# Interbase SQL Grouping and displaying

Tags: interbase

I have a database with different data I need to make a query to select a group with summed quantities.

Two tables: `Positions` and `Documents`.

There can be many positions in one document both are connected by `unique_id`.

The Documents have two different statuses: `In` and `Out`

I need to see the result of these two status on one row with a column for each case, but instead my query gives me two rows. How do I do it?

My query doesn't give me this result:

```
Select   documents.code
        ,positions.fullname
        ,case when documents.status='In' then Sum(positions.quantity) else 0 end as DocIn
        ,case when documents.status='Out' then Sum(positions.quantity) else 0 end as DocOut
from positions
    inner join documents
        on documents.unique_id=positions.unique_id
group by documents.code, positions.fullname, documents.status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting two rows per document because you are grouping by `documents.status`. You need to use `SUM()` slightly differently and then remove `documents.status` from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Select   documents.code
        ,positions.fullname
        ,SUM(case when documents.status='In' THEN positions.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS DocIn
        ,SUM(case when documents.status='Out' THEN positions.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS DocOut
from positions 
inner join documents
 on documents.unique_id=positions.unique_id 
 group by documents.code, positions.fullname
```

Comment: Hmm... Let me try

Comment: IBExpert says "Nested aggregate functions are not allowed."

Comment: You're doing something different from the suggested solution. This solution does not have nested aggregate functions.

Comment: Oh yeh.. Thank you all so much. I forgot to remove **Sum(positions.quantity)** within the case function.